# Concerns about python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've some concerns about the working of [python](/questions/tagged/python) [jupyter-notebook](/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook).

When I `print()` something then, everything seems correct (*or familiar*), but when I just return something rather than `print()`ing, then there is `Out[x]` before the output. As shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

So, I wanted to know how these two are different from each other?

Are the `Out[x]` statements somehow used for debugging or what?

Comment: I've never use the Notebook, but that's likely just so you can tell what's printed due to being returned, and what's printed due to `print`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, might be possible, but I think that the case should be reversed. I mean, when we use `print` then it should show `Out[x]`. I think that would be more genuine. Don't you think so?

Comment: It may allow you to refer to previously returned data via the numbers. Haskell's REPL allows this iirc. It wouldn't make as much sense to try to refer to printed strings. I think "out" should be interpreted as "data out" (not printed out), just like the "In" seems to indicate "Data/code in to the REPL". I agree though that "out" can be ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I didn't think that way! Thanks bud

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Jupyter intro tutorial", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @Prune Certainly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out by the help of [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855313/concerns-about-python-notebook?noredirect=1#comment94558678_53855313).

All the previously returned data is refer-able in later commands/inputs, that's why they all are numerically numbered.

It would be redundant to refer printed data later, but this would be useful if we can refer the returned data later.

And this can be done in two ways (*In my knowledge*)

**First**: The last returned value can be obtained by `_` variable, like so:

```
In [1]: 'Hello Everyone' # This returns a string
Out[1]: 'Hello Everyone'

In [2]: print('Last returned value is ' + _)
# Ouput -> Last returned value is Hello Everyone
```

**Second**: We can explicitly mention the number to get the specified returned value, like so:

```
In [3]: 4 + 6
Out[3]: 10
In [4]: 6 + 4
Out[4]: 10
In [5]: print(Out[3] + Out[4])
# Output -> 20
```

---

Keep in mind that if the mentioned `Out[]` does not have any returned value then this will raise a `KeyError`

Here, *return* does not mean *print*. If any value is `print()`ed then, that will not be considered as returned.

We can also mention our written code by `In[x]`, this will return that code in form of a string, like this:

```
In [6]: print('This was my first code: ' + In[1])
# Output -> This was my first code: Hello Everyone
In [7]: In[4]
Out[7]: '6 + 4'
```